# The order in layout changes after i put the custom layout resource file in listview

Tags: android, xml

[image]I made a good code in which the text 1 schedule here and 2 schedule here were aligned similar vertically. But i put this layout in list view and so the 7 names of days are not same, layout is changed.my custom layout had this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listback">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="80dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Day name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/dayname" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 schedule here"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/mytext1"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 schedule here"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/mytext2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Total"
                android:id="@+id/totaltext" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/lightStatus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So how can i manage layout so that my 1 schedule and 2 schedule texts will be in same line vertically after i put them in list view

Image putting list view is shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try to this xml code hope this can help you...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dayname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Wednesday"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Nov 18 2016 Friday"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="no day available"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totaltext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="no day available"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lightStatus"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />    
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```